# no se encontro el nombre de archivo o de ensamblado "System.Core"

Tags: c#, embebido, windows-mobile

cuando ejecuto mi aplicacion directamente desde el dispositivo movil este me arroja este error, compruebo en mi proyecto y el ensamblado si se encuentra ahi con la version que indica el error que es el 3.5.0.0 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cual seria la solucion para este error que se me esta presentando

Comment: fijate que en copia local dice false.. no se a que dispositivo lo mueves ni como lo ejecutas, pero lo mas probable es q no vaya con tu aplicacion. (y por lo que veo, no deberia ir)

Comment: No basta con tener el ensamblado en la máquina, a veces hay que hacer una referencia a mano hasta el ensamblado desde el proyecto. ¿Qué IDE estas usando?

Comment: @gbianchi lo que pasa es que si quito esa dll pues me arroja error con este using System.Linq;

Comment: ¿Pero que IDE usas? ¿Visual Studio?

Comment: @Awes0meM4n utilizo Visual Studio 2008 Proyecto SmartDevice

Comment: El IDE es el entorno de desarrollo, en tu caso VS2008. Ahora te respondo con lo que hice en su dia con un caso parecido.

Answer (score 2):

En el device tienes que instalar el framework de .net compact

[.NET Compact Framework 3.5 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=65)

tienes que tener el framework de .net en el device para que funcione, no funciona si lo lo tienes en la pc donde desarrollas

[Cómo: Instalar .NET Compact Framework en un dispositivo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/bb788171(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: pues hago lo que dice ese link y el resultado es el mismo

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te falta una referencia al ensamblado que te pide. Usa el [enlace de MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.120).aspx) que te dice los pasos para hacer lo que te digo. Si no lo consigues seguimos con otra cosa.

Comment: Mismo resultado me sigue apareciendo

Comment: Asegurate de que hay hecho lo que te he dicho y lo que te ha dicho @Leandro Tuttini. Si lo tienes bien hecho con la misma versión y se ejecuta en el IDE bien el problema lo tienes en el dispositivo móvil.

Comment: ya hice todo lo que dice usted y leandro pero aun asi me sigue saliendo el error

Comment: @CristianR.M Lo siento pero yo no tengo Visual Studio, hace tiempo que deje de usarlo y la experiencia que tenía es la que te dije. Deberías de ponerte en contacto con Microsoft para que te guíen en el empaquetado de todas las librerías que te hacen falta para que tu aplicación se ejecute correctamente.